# Beamer - A whole new table of content for each section

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

As you can see in the picture, I managed to get 2 tables of
contents before each start of `section`.
However, what I want is that :

The `Table of Contents of Section 1` will just give
`section 1`, `sub-section 1.1` and `sub-section 1.2`, without
`section 2` or any of its subsections involved.
Basically, you can think that I want to "hide" the second part,
but it is not exactly what I mean. What I want exactly is :
In `Table of Contents of Section 1`, it will make the `TOC 1`
as if this document JUST HAS `section 1`, `sub-section 1.1` and `sub-section 1.2`
ONLY. So `Table of Contents of Section 1` will be vertically centered.

The same thing is required for `Table of Contents of Section 2`, 
and as it is required, the number of bullet before `section 2` should be `1`
NOT `2` (because this time, it will make the `TOC 2`
as if this document JUST HAS `section 2`, `sub-section 2.1` and `sub-section 2.2`).

Thank you in advance.

[image]

```
\documentclass[18pt]{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Warsaw}
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[triangle]
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[triangle]
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}[triangle]
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
    \useoutertheme{infolines}
    \usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}
%\frame{\tableofcontents}

\section{section 1}

\begin{frame}{Table of Contents of Section 1}
\tableofcontents[currentsection,
]
\end{frame}

  \begin{frame}
    section 1
  \end{frame}

  \subsection{sub-sectiion 1.1}

    \begin{frame}
      section 1.1
    \end{frame}

  \subsection{sub-sectiion 1.2}

    \begin{frame}
      section 1.2
    \end{frame}

\section{section 2}


\begin{frame}{Table of Contents of Section 2}
\tableofcontents[currentsection,
]
\end{frame}

  \begin{frame}
    section 2
  \end{frame}

  \subsection{sub-sectiion 2.1}

    \begin{frame}
      section 2.1
    \end{frame}

  \subsection{sub-sectiion 2.2}

    \begin{frame}
      section 2.2
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're asking for, the following command should do that:

```
\tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/hide,subsectionstyle=show/show/hide]
```

As explained in section 10.5 of `beamer` manual, the option `currentsection` is equivalent to `sectionstyle=show/shaded,subsectionstyle=show/show/shaded`. Since you want to completely eliminate the "other" sections and subsections, you can change `shaded` to `hide`.

This is the complete code:

```
\documentclass[18pt]{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Warsaw}
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[triangle]
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[triangle]
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}[triangle]
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
    \useoutertheme{infolines}
    \usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}
%\frame{\tableofcontents}

\section{section 1}

\begin{frame}{Table of Contents of Section 1}
\tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/hide,subsectionstyle=show/show/hide]
\end{frame}

  \begin{frame}
    section 1
  \end{frame}

  \subsection{sub-sectiion 1.1}

    \begin{frame}
      section 1.1
    \end{frame}

  \subsection{sub-sectiion 1.2}

    \begin{frame}
      section 1.2
    \end{frame}

\section{section 2}


\begin{frame}{Table of Contents of Section 2}
\tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/hide,subsectionstyle=show/show/hide]
\end{frame}

  \begin{frame}
    section 2
  \end{frame}

  \subsection{sub-sectiion 2.1}

    \begin{frame}
      section 2.1
    \end{frame}

  \subsection{sub-sectiion 2.2}

    \begin{frame}
      section 2.2
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: TOC1]
[image: TOC2]

Comment: OK. I will use this in my presentation. Thank you.

Comment: I am sorry to bother again. But there is a minor question. See the pictures have section names on the headline, but I don't want them appearing. (The same problem for my old code). A usual `TOC` after the title page won't have a section name on the headline. Do you know how to clear the text (Even manual setting for each section is fine) ?

Comment: OK, I use `\begin{frame}[plain]` to remove completely headline of these specific frames.